# File does not exist at path

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem deploying a system on the server for free 000webhostapp.com.
I uploaded all the files organized in the public_http folders and another on the same level, then made the changes in the path to execute correctly.
I configured access to the database.
I'm stopped at the following error:

```
File does not exist at path /storage/ssd3/597/5201597/test/resources/views/client/external/includes/scripts.blade.php (View: / storage / ssd3 / 597/5201597 / test / resources / views / client / external / includes / scripts.blade.php)
```

I've tapped on the folders and the file exists, but there's nothing inside.

Would anyone have any ideas that might help me?

Comment: did you set your root folder into public instead of public_http?

Comment: Can you determine if the file exists for this path? Including the same case? `/storage/ssd3/597/5201597/test/resources/views/client/external/includes/scripts.blade.php`

Comment: @TonzFale 
inside the public_http folder is just the contents of my public folder and I have changed the index to the correct path, the rest of the code is inside a "project" folder in the root.

Comment: @qskane Yes it does, but the way is resources/views/client/external/includes/scripts.blade.php. The server put /storage/ssd3/597/5201597/test before, i don't undestend.

Answer (score -1):

Please use `Storage_path()` function of laravel or `public_path()` of laravel

where `storage_path()` will store the image,or all files in the storage folder of laravel and

`public_path()` will store in the public folder in laravel

Make sure what function you are using the blade to display...you can also use 
`asset()` function to reach to your file path

Comment: Neither `storage_path()` nor `public_path()` stores files. They return paths to a given file.

Comment: @jaydave 
It was not me that developed the code, but from what I understood this function is being called in the filesystem.php file that is in the internal folder created by laravel / vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Filesystem / it requests the file scripts.blade .php file that exists in the resources / views / client / external / includes path.
I do not know where the rest of the way back came from / storage / ssd3 / 597/5201597 / test
I tested it on a local server and it worked but not on the server.